# Trying to select from a list the first previous eligible index

Tags: c#, list

I have a `List<List<Object>>` in which one of these objects has the property `isCurrentlySelected = true`. This nested list represents a grid of these objects that might be constructed in any configuration (i.e. the grid may be any dimensions, and may even be jagged).

Now, some of these objects have the property `isSelectable = false`, so I'm trying to create a  method which takes a single parameter for "direction" and returns the first eligible index in the specified direction from the one currently marked as selected.

So far I've only been able to do this using several nested for loops and if-else statements, and even then, it will only work for one direction. I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to check for the first eligible element, preferably using a single method.

Thanks in advance for any help,

~KWiP

**EDIT: with code sample**

So I have the `Menu` class:

```
public class Menu
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
        public int width;
        public int height;
        public int lineHeight;
        public float menuTimer = 0.0f;
        public bool menuKeysPressed = false;
        public List<List<Selection>> selections = new List<List<Selection>>();
        public int selectedList = 0;
        public int selectedItem = 0;
```

in which is the child class `Selection`:

```
public class Selection
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
            public bool isCurrentlySelected = false;
            public bool isSelectable = true;
            public Color selectedColor = Color.White;
            public Color unselectedColor = Color.Gray;
            public bool isNonText = false;
            public string displayText = "";
            public int textSize;

            public Selection(int xPos, int yPos, string text, int size, bool selectable)
            {
                x = xPos;
                y = yPos;
                displayText = text;
                textSize = size;
                if (!selectable)
                {
                    isCurrentlySelected = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Each `Selection` in a `Menu` object has X and Y coordinates in the form of its indices in the nested lists found in `Menu.selections`. In each Menu, there is typically exactly one `Selection` with its `isCurrentlySelected` property set to true.

```
public Menu(int xPos, int yPos, int wdth, int hght, int lists = 0, int items = 0, bool allSelectable = true)
        {
            x = xPos;
            y = yPos;
            width = wdth;
            height = hght;
            if (items > 0 && lists <= 0)
            {
                lists = 1;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < lists; i++)
            {
                selections.Add(new List<Selection>());
                for (int j = 0; j < items; j++)
                {
                    selections.ElementAt(i).Add(new Selection(((wdth / items) * j) + xPos, ((hght / lists) * i) + yPos, "", 20, allSelectable));
                }
            }
            if (items > 0)
            {
                selections.ElementAt(0).ElementAt(0).isCurrentlySelected = true;
            }
        }
```

Now, within the `Menu` class, I'm trying to make a method which will deselect the currently selected index, and then select the next closest eligible index in a particular direction, wrapping around to the other side if the end of the range of indices is reached. Unfortunately, all I've been able to come up with is this mess, which currently only works going North, and would need to be expanded to roughly 4x its size to accommodate all directions.

```
public void nav(Point currentSelected, int dir) // The 4 cardinal directions are represented by an int: 0 for North and continuing clockwise from there.
        {
            int newRow = currentSelected.Y;
            int newIndex = currentSelected.X;
            switch (dir)
            {
                case 0: // Operations to select next eligible N index.
                    if (this.selections.Count <= 1)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int firstOpenRow = this.selections.Count;
                        for (int i = 0; i < this.selections.Count; i++)
                        {
                            int difference = i - currentSelected.Y;
                            if (difference > 0 && difference < firstOpenRow && this.selections.ElementAt(i).ElementAt(currentSelected.X).isSelectable == true)
                            {
                                firstOpenRow = i;
                            }
                        }
                        if (firstOpenRow == this.selections.Count)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < this.selections.Count; i++)
                            {
                                int difference = i - currentSelected.Y;
                                if (difference < 0 && difference < firstOpenRow && this.selections.ElementAt(i).ElementAt(currentSelected.X).isSelectable == true)
                                {
                                    firstOpenRow = i;
                                }
                            }
                            if (firstOpenRow == this.selections.Count)
                            {
                                firstOpenRow = currentSelected.Y;
                            }
                        }
                        this.selections.ElementAt(currentSelected.Y).ElementAt(currentSelected.X).isCurrentlySelected = false;
                        this.selections.ElementAt(firstOpenRow).ElementAt(currentSelected.X).isCurrentlySelected = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // Add operations for E here
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // Add operations for S here
                    break;
                case 3:
                    // Add operations for W here
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please post some code that demonstrates what you've tried so far and clarifies the issue.

Comment: How do you define "index"? Don't you need a coordinate *pair*?

Comment: I don't see a problem in iterating in the opposite direction. You could have two nested loops in the format: `for(int i = maxValue, i >= 0; i++)`. As for avoiding nested loops. I would recommend a different data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your choice of data-structure isn't really well made for the kind of queries you need to make. Maybe you should consider investing a little more time into creating a linked grid. Something like:

```
class Item
{
    Item North { get; private set; }
    Item South { get; private set; }
    Item West { get; private set; }
    Item East { get; private set; }
}
```

Like that, if you look for the next 'left' item, you can just go West until you either reach **null** or you encounter an item that is selectable.

Otherwise, it makes sense to distinguish between the different kinds of directions. Just because you have less code doesn't mean your program runs faster. Think of your algorithm in terms of how many operations you have to make to reach your goal, instead of how long it is.

Sorry if that's not the answer your're looking for.

Comment: I completely agree that this data structure isn't particularly well-suited for what I'm doing, but as I'm a fairly new programmer, this was the best thing I could think of. Having said that though, pre-defining the indeces in each direction sounds like a great idea that I think will work. But out of curiosity, how would you structure the data differently?

Comment: Hey! Well it depends :). If you need to access say the 3rd item in the 2nd column, then you go on with a List of a List. But you have the navigation parts are crucial, there. Otherwise, just throw them into a list.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I follow. So what I'm doing here is making a grid of objects that represent items in a menu. These objects can be arranged in a grid of any dimension, possibly jagged, and I will capture keyboard input in order to navigate from one item to another, highlighting (via text color) the currently selected item.

I suppose my question becomes, is a two-dimensional list of these objects the best choice? Or should I have taken a different route?

Comment: I think, for now the List of list is fine.